# How do I hide the page title in Drupal 7?

Tags: 7

I'm a site administrator for my university and I'm using Drupal through their servers, but I can't figure out how to hide the page title from the screen. I can't install modules because I'm not on their lab computer (using my personal laptop and I don't have the permission to) and I don't see anything that I can uncheck that says "Automatically update Menu Title". Is there a way to work around this? Or does this mean I have to use my school's lab computers?

Answer (score 1):

You can update the template for the Content type or that specific node.

I tend to use CSS to hide the page element if it is only one page title/node I am trying to hide.

Comment: What if I can't access the CSS files??

Comment: @Karen You can add the css (inside the correct tags) to the body field.

Comment: <style>
blahblah {
    visibility: hidden;
}
</style>

Answer (score 1):

If you can't install modules, can't access templates and can't access css, and that functionality is not already built into the site - then it is not possible to do this by just using the admin GUI.

This is a trivial task if you've access to templates and/or css. But to do it using the admin GUI, you need to first write and install a small module that adds a checkbox to do this to the admin GUI.